# Why is the autorouter not reaching 100%?

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

When I use the autorouter in eagle for creating simple traces (the more difficult ones I'm doing on my own) it stops at 98.2%, but no trace is left unrouted. Why don't I get 100%? How do I find out the problematic areas?

Comment: The Eagle autorouter is rubbish. The advanced autorouter (it costs extra) in the rather expensive Pulsonix package that I use is quite good, but I always route the supply lines myself. I don't use it very often, though.

Comment: @Leon: The Eagle autorouter is a decent tool I've used many times with good results.  You do have to sit down and really learn all the controls though.  Most people don't bother to really learn it, and then blame the auto-router for the bad results.

Answer (score 1):

The Eagle autorouter sometimes cannot make the final connection to certain pads, especially if they don't align with the routing grid. If you turn off all of the layers except for the ratsnest ("unrouted"), you'll see tiny little marks where those failed connections are. You can just touch them up with manual routing.

Comment: The thing is that I can not see any unrouted traces left. Is there a command to highlight them? (And yes, I already hid all the other parts)

Comment: They are *really tiny*, sometimes just points. You really need to zoom in and search for them. I don't know of any built-in way to highlight them, but I suppose you could write a script of some sort. I never bothered.

Comment: If you start a new route in a random place, eagle will try to connect it to the nearest non-yet-fully-routed 'edge'. Look at that place for rastnest line (might need magnification).

Comment: Agreed. What I do is zoom out until the entire design is only displayed on a small portion of the screen.  Then I start a new route and click on the design.  The cursor will be close enough to any unrouted airwire that it will grab onto it.