# Eagle Auto Router Display

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, autorouter

I've been having difficulty finishing the routing on a PCB I've designed. This is the first time this has happened really. I have miles of free space, yet it only gets to 96.4%. Anyways, I can't find what these readings mean that display on the bottom left of my screen while auto router is running. Can someone please explain what the numbers mean?

[image]

Comment: perhaps the rest is space which ist blocked by the system itself?
did do try to get help from a pbc designers help section or faq, i.e. this one: http://www.cadsoftusa.com/training-service/support/

Comment: Does it go to 100% during routing,v and then jump back to 96% near the end, or does it never get to 100?

Comment: Related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/148926/11683

Answer (score 2):

The line you mention means that there are 659 connections to be made and 635 of them ended up made. Also, the autorouter placed 605 vias (which seems like a lot to me).

You should check the DRC, specifically the clearance tab.  You might have the clearances set looser than they need to be for the fabricator you're using.  For example, maybe you could move traces nearer to pads than you are right now.

If the routing reaches 100% and then drops back, I find that that's usually because the ground plane fell apart, and now some things that seemed grounded have lost their reference.  Paradoxically, the way I can often fix that is to set my DRC to leave MORE room around my vias, so that the ground plane can sneak through them.  This may do bad things to my copper pour, so I manually check to make sure that nothing bad happened where I most need continuous ground planes.

You need to find out where your failures to route are.  Hit ratsnest, and view layer 19 in isolation if the misses aren't apparent.  Look for the signals on the unrouted traces.  If they're mostly GND, your problem is the ground plane breaking up.

If all else fails, consider more layers, or routing the tough bits by hand.